# Chromedriver is writing `scoped_dir` to Program Files (x86)

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I do my testing with Chromedriver using a Azure DevOps agent on a server in my network to start each test (.NET core based).
When I do the tests Chrome is creating a scoped_dir directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\ but not cleaning it up. What property should I change or what is causing this?

I checked the driver capabilities which states a user data dir should be located in C:\Windows\proxy which is also weird to me and which I cannot find on the system. I would have expected a temp folder, but maybe that proxy does that (wrong in my case)...

Driver capabilities:

```
{
  "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "browserVersion": "113.0.5672.64",
  "chrome": {
    "chromedriverVersion": "113.0.5672.24 (65f30d4e8051264233c679c7cd3743679f15339d-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#243})",
    "userDataDir": "C:\\Windows\\proxy\\scoped_dir3604_1404454725"
  },
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
    "debuggerAddress": "localhost:3048"
  },
....
}
```

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4322